# Python code, copied from book & website but still not working 3.4

Tags: python, encryption

First of, i'm sort of new to Python so sorry if this question is obvious. The detect english module appears to be wrong, but it functions perfectly fine when calling it and running it on its own, theres no errors when running it alone and i've rewritten it a couple times to triple check it.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "H:\Python\Python Cipher Program\transposition hacker.py", line 49, in <module>
    main()
 File "H:\Python\Python Cipher Program\transposition hacker.py", line 11, in   main
 hackedMessage = hackTransposition(myMessage)
 File "H:\Python\Python Cipher Program\transposition hacker.py", line 34, in hackTransposition
  if detectEnglish.isEnglish(decryptedText):
File "H:\Python\Python Cipher Program\detectEnglish.py", line 48, in isEnglish
 wordsMatch = getEnglishCount(message) * 100 >= wordPercentage
 TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'int'
```

this is the error i am getting when trying to run the Transposition Hacker (copied directly from [here](http://inventwithpython.com/transpositionHacker.py)

Here is the code for the Detect English Module 
       # Detect english Module

```
# to use this code
# import detectEnglish
# detectEnglish.isEnglish(somestring)
# returns true of false
# there must be a dictionary.txt file in the same directory
# all english words
# one per line

UPPERLETTERS = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
LETTERS_AND_SPACE = UPPERLETTERS + UPPERLETTERS.lower() + ' \t\n'


def loadDictionary()
 dictionaryFile = open('Dictionary.txt')
englishWords = {}
for word in dictionaryFile.read().split('\n'):
    englishWords[word] = None
dictionaryFile.close()
return englishWords

 ENGLISH_WORDS = loadDictionary()

def getEnglishCount(message):
message = message.upper()
message = removeNonLetters(message)
possibleWords = message.split()
if possibleWords == []:
    return 0.0

matches = 0
for word in possibleWords:
    if word in ENGLISH_WORDS:
        matches += 1
        return float(matches) / len(possibleWords)

def removeNonLetters(message):
lettersOnly = []
for symbol in message:
    if symbol in LETTERS_AND_SPACE:
        lettersOnly.append(symbol)
return ''.join(lettersOnly)

def isEnglish(message, wordPercentage=20, letterPercentage=85):
# by default 20% of the words mustr exist in dictionary file
# 85% of charecters in messafe must be spaces or letters
wordsMatch = getEnglishCount(message) * 100 >= wordPercentage
numLetters = len(removeNonLetters(message))
messageLettersPercentage = float(numLetters) / len(message) * 100
lettersMatch = messageLettersPercentage >= letterPercentage
return wordsMatch and lettersMatcht
```

Comment: `getEnglishCount` doesn't return anything if all the words in `possibleWords` are not in `ENGLISH_WORDS`. I think your `return float(matches) / len(possibleWords)` is improperly indented, and should go outside of the for loop.

Comment: fix your indentation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getEnglishCount` looks like it is missing a return statement. If python gets to the end of a function without hitting a return statement it will return `None` as you're seeing.

try this:

```
def getEnglishCount(message):
    message = message.upper()
    message = removeNonLetters(message)
    possibleWords = message.split()
    # if possibleWords == []:  # redundant
    #     return 0.0
    return len(possibleWords)
```

**Edit:** @Kevin Yea I think you're right - there was more in that function. Maybe try this:

```
def getEnglishCount(message):
    message = message.upper()
    message = removeNonLetters(message)
    possibleWords = message.split()
    if possibleWords == []:
        return 0.0

    matches = 0.
    for word in possibleWords:
        if word in ENGLISH_WORDS:
            matches += 1
    return matches / len(possibleWords)
```

I'd guess the indentation somehow got changed when you copy and pasted the code, with the return statement nested under the `if`.

Comment: I think the OP improperly formatted his code sample, and the function actually continues up until right before `def removeNonLetters(message):`. So I agree that he should have a final return statement, but I think it should go after the `for word in possibleWords:` loop.

Comment: I would say just ``return len(possibleWords)`` in any case

Comment: I think `return float(matches) / len(possibleWords)` is in `getEnglishCount`. Anyway, this is impossible to figure out unless the OP properly indent their code.

Comment: Thank you so much! I've been stuck with this problem for 2 days (i'm learning Python and this one problem has nagged me)! Is there a way to close this question or something? I'm new to this forum aswell

Comment: @BrandonSkerritt No problem! Just keep in mind that indentation matters in python

Comment: No need to close the question or anything. Just mark an answer as accepted (thanks!), nothing more for you to do :)

Answer (score 0):

As the other poster has said, you're missing a return for the getEnglishCount method, so it's returning NoneType, meaning that there is no value to be returned.

You can't do math on NoneTypes, so the NoneType*100 fails, which is what the bottom of your error traceback says.